# Python Multidimensional Array - Adding additional values to beginning and end of each row

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy, iteration

How do I add 0's to the beginning and end of each row of a multidimensional array? This is the function I am trying to apply to each row.

```
def zero(ltr):
  for x in range (1,int((N+1)/2)):
        ltr = append(([0]), ltr)
        ltr = append(ltr,([0]))
  return ltr
```

I have tried using both

```
for row in a:
   zero(row)
```

and 
`apply_along_axis(zero,1,a)` 
Neither one of these commands does what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to add entries to single rows of a two-dimensional array.  All rows must always have the same length.  But you can add entries to all rows at once.

If `a` is a two-dimensional NumPy array, you can use `numpy.hstack` to add zeros to left and the right:

```
a = numpy.array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.],
                 [  4.,   5.,   6.,   7.],
                 [  8.,   9.,  10.,  11.]])
numpy.hstack((numpy.zeros((a.shape[0], 2)), a, numpy.zeros((a.shape[0], 1))))
# array([[  0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   0.],
#        [  0.,   0.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   0.],
#        [  0.,   0.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,   0.]])
```

For the sake of example, I added `2` zeros to the left and `1` zero to the right.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I see you're already using `numpy`. I'll leave this for the sake of education, but you should use `hstack` as in [Sven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456477/python-multidimensional-array-adding-additional-values-to-beginning-and-end-of/4456512#4456512).

```
>>> a = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
>>> for row in a:
...     row.insert(0, 0)
...     row.append(0)
...
>>> a
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
```

or if you prefer:

```
>>> import operator
>>> a = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
>>> map(operator.methodcaller("insert", 0, 0), a)
[None, None, None]
>>> map(operator.methodcaller("append", 0), a)
[None, None, None]
>>> a
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
```